# Multi screen in Android

Tags: android, size, screen

i used specifies pixel size  for several screen size in Android.

For EX : layout-800x480 or drawable-800x480.

We have two sizes of 5.1 inches, a 4-inch  for 480x800. How to make a folder and say which one I need? I want both.

Comment: You should take a look at the Android page about multiple screens: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: i read this web site. but that is not solve my problem

Comment: You should work with dpi, not pixel.

Comment: can u give me an example? i created folder "layout-800x480"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the folder layout-800x480 and if you want pictures this resolution specifies you have to create the folder drawable-800x480 or you can use the default folder hdpi, xhdpi, etc...

More info [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: we have 2 size for 800x480 pixel. 5.1"inch and 4"inch. i need 2 layout for 4"inch and 5.1"inch layout

Comment: If you just want those two sizes yes.

Comment: i couldn't create 2 folder with same name. one for 5.1"inch and another for 4"inch.(layout-800x480) i need 4inch size for layout and 5.1inch size for other layout

Comment: You have to created two folder for the two resolution. In eclipse when you create an android xml choose the layout option and then makes you want to set the size. Here I leave a video that explains more or less http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8dGQEN9sRs

Comment: in this situation we have one resolution for 2 size.(4inch and 5.1inch) did you mean user have to choose exact size in program when activity started? and i have to manage in my app?

Comment: The video explains that.

Comment: thank you for your help. i'm going to watch the video. again thank you for your time.

Comment: this video didn't answer my question. for example i have lenovo a3000 tablet witch is 7"inch but 170ppi and i have galaxy s3 mini 4"inch and 233ppi. i had to use exact size. ( i use layout-1280x800 instead of layout-xlarge)

Comment: If you want exact size yes. You have to use layout-1280x800

Comment: i told you we have several inch in same resolution. for ex : we have 2 size for 800x480 pixel. 5.1"inch and 4"inch. i need both. 4"inch and 5.1"inch layout

Comment: Ok sorry. You can only have one layout with a resolution independent of inches. You must make adaptive layout to two inches that you have. If the problem you are the images do not worry about that android will catch the image of that inch dpi of these images are in folders "xhdpi, hdpi, etc.."